# Change alignment of first line in automatically wrapped div with CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, word-wrap

I have a div that contains text that should be automatically broken into several lines. To indicate the fact that this line break happened because of text wrapping i want to align all wrapped lines right and keep the first line left-aligned.

Like this:

```
--------- Fixed Width -----------
| This is an automatically      |
| __               wrapped line |
---------------------------------

-----------------------------
| FirstName SecondName      |
| __       VeryLongLastName |
-----------------------------
```

The `::first-line`-CSS-Selector is not allowed to change the `text-align`-Property and `text-align-last` property only works with text that uses `text-align: justify`, which would not produce the desired results, so i do not know how to do this.

To make it look good it probably also needs an "indentation" parameter, so any of the following lines cannot fill up the whole width by accident. (`_`)

Is this even possible in HTML/CSS?

With multiple lines (but should be very uncommon in my usecase.):

```
--------- Fixed Width -------------
| With a longer text it should    |
| __  look like this. You can see |
| __     that the other lines are |
| __               right aligned. |
-----------------------------------
```

The desired result is very similar to the [LaTeX amsmath multiline-environment](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath#/Displaying_long_equations), but i cannot set the breakpoint by hand, but want to use automatic word wrapping instead.

Comment: did you try with a `<ul>` instead?

Comment: No, not yet. And i'm not sure in how i could use that to solve my problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Take a look and tell me if it is useful: [fiddle](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/egELKO)

Comment: I wanted to use automatic word wrapping. Your fiddle looks like i would have to predefine which text would be left/right-aligned. (And the first line in the cells is also right aligned) I only used the `_` in my example to indicate the "indentation". A space that is blocked for the right aligned lines.